# Delete duplicate assets from Salesforce

Tags: duplicates, salesforce, assets, soql

I came to know that there are several duplicate assets in our Salesforce sandbox org. To do a cleaner testing of my current assignment, I need to cleanup the duplicate assets. Under each account, I could see that there are multiple active assets for the same product.

I ran the below query and it is fetching the duplicate counts.

```
SELECT  AccountId, ProductCode, COUNT(Id)
FROM Asset
WHERE ProductCode != null AND RecordType.Name = 'Internal' and IsActive__c = true
GROUP BY AccountId, ProductCode
HAVING COUNT(Id) > 1
LIMIT 100
```

Is there a way to retain only the most recent active asset and delete the remaining ones?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Untested but along these lines.
You might have to run it several times or add your own filter on Accounts to somehow slice data.

```java
List<Asset> toDelete = new List<Asset>();

for(Account acc : [SELECT Id,
    (SELECT ProductCode
    FROM Assets
    WHERE ProductCode != null AND RecordType.Name = 'Internal' and IsActive__c = true
    ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC)
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Asset WHERE ProductCode != null AND RecordType.Name = 'Internal' and IsActive__c = true)
    LIMIT 1000]){

    Set<String> productCodes = new Set<String>();
    for(Asset a : acc.Assets){
        if(productCodes.contains(a.ProductCode)){
            toDelete.add(a);
        } else {
            productCodes.add(a.ProductCode);
        }
    }
}

delete toDelete;
```

Probably you can simplify it a bit, from what I remember `set.add` returns boolean saying whether collection has modified as result of the addition.